# Winginx NPM Global packages folder

Tags: node.js, npm, winginx

I am beginner on node.js. Actually my intention are setup portable environment for development node.js on windows. Wingnix are good candidates since it include nginx, mysql, and php.

I install the npm package via -g (global flag), however, it stored in my ${APPDATA}\npm due to the npmrc file on 
    C:\Winginx\nodejs\node_modules\npm

However, as in the documentation of Winginx for node.js section

> As you know, Node.js supports packages (modules). Global packages
>   folder is \winginx\nodejs\node_modules.
>
> Node.js Package Manager NPM, popular Node.js web framework Express.js
>   and template engine Jade are included.

That make me confuse, how i install additional global package and manage them? do Winginx provide command shell to manage? Because i set the ***\winginx\nodejs*** as Path in environment variables for access through Bash/CMD in windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this bat file: X:\winginx\nodejs\npm.cmd